# MailingState field showing statecode instead of state/province Name

Tags: visualforce, email-template, vf-email-template

I am writing a visualforce email template and trying to show the recipient's mailingState Name. My piece of code is given below:

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!$Label.GDPREmailTemplatelabel1}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Contact">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!recipient.MailingState!=NULL}">
{!recipient.MailingState},<br/>
</apex:outputPanel> 
</messaging:htmlEmailBody >
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I have country/territory enabled.
I am getting mailingStateCode as output instead of State/Province Name.
[image]
Is there anyway to get the State/Province name?

Comment: Try using `<apex:outputField value="{!recipient.MailingState}" />`

Comment: Sorry. It didn't work.

Comment: Was a guess, apparently VF email templates behave different from VF pages :-(